# Преобразование шрифта в массив

Tags: c, шрифты, embedded

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, утилиты (доступные для скачивания) для преобразования шрифта в заголовочный файл `*.h` с массивом, содержащим растр для всех нужных символов для использования во встраиваемых системах.

Типа такого: `Freescale Embedded GUI Converter Utility 2.0` (судя по всему, его так просто не скачать).

Comment: Весьма понравился редактор SG Bitmap Font Editor. Шрифт, может, и надо допиливать, но сразу видно, что он сделал и что надо редактировать. Формат массива данных простой и удобный. Ну и можно экспортировать в бинарный файл (который потом переводится в массив много чем).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156572/c-header-file-with-bitmapped-fonts/2156872#2156872) на stackoverflow. Предлагается использовать утилиту convert из imagemagick.
Например команда:

```
convert -resize 7x13\! -font /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf -pointsize 10 label:A A.xbm
```

генерирует побитовое представление буквы A:

```
#define A_width 7
#define A_height 13
static char A_bits[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x0C, 0x0A, 0x0A, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x11, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 
  0x00, };
```